# unable to migrate djcelery in django 1.5.4

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

I am working on django 1.5.4 and want to implement celery on my project. I installed celery (latest version) and then django-celery package.

on my `settings.py`, I have included following lines

```
import djcelery
djcelery.setup_loader()
INSTALLED_APPS = (
   # other apps,
   'djcelery',
)
```

As I try to migrate djcelery (using south), it gives following error:

```
lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 134, in    
__init__
raise ImportError("Could not import settings '%s' (Is it on sys.path?): %s" % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e)) 
ImportError: Could not import settings 'settings' (Is it on sys.path?): cannot import name Celery
```

I can't understand what is causing this error, cause I have installed both celery and Django-celery properly on my project's virtual environment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I too had similar problem before which was casued by `celery.pyc` file within my project folder. Try removing `celery.pyc`, that might solve your problem.